# Do all animals with eyesight get an upside-down image on their retina, or is it right-side up with some?

Tags: eyes, senses, optics

here's as good an image as any for showing the thing about human vision that I am asking about: [image]

So, our retina gets an upside-down image.

My question is, do all animals' eyes work this way? Or do some have their cells report the image as-is?

Comment: How do you know that ours don't? How would you tell if another animal does?

Comment: "*Or do some have their cells report the image as-is?*" You can't objectively make judgements about perception since perception is subjective. You might as well ask what the colour red looks to different animals. Think carefully about what you mean when you say "report image as is". Relative to what? Relative to your inner ear says is down? That's not going to change how you interpret the world because "down" in the image is still going to be perceived as "down" in your ear.

Comment: Look at your image (which is not quite right, btw.). Where, exactly, does the angle of light entering your eye change (there are actually three places). Any animal with a cornea and a convex lens will have an inverted image on their retina if their eyeball is deep enough. All you need to do is a search for which animals don't have the above to know if they have an inverted image on their retina or not.

Comment: https://www.cell.com/current-biology/pdf/S0960-9822(05)00441-0.pdf

Comment: @bob1 - Physics. Plain old physics. This has been studied **extensively** in almost every animal. Not sure exactly why, but it has, and it's interesting.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I was thinking along the lines of insects, crustaceans etc, where there is no lens etc. My point was to get OP to think.

Comment: "How would you tell if another animal does?" Ah, I didn't read this carefully enough. Thanks.